# refactoring Class component to function Component with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I am trying to refactor a Class component into a Function component in a react-redux app, but I am a bit stuck. When I try to convert this Component to a function Component, this line of code **this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)** no longer executes and it cannot read the **list** portion of code declared within the variables underneath the **renderWeather()** function

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { connect, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Chart from "../containers/Chart";


class WeatherList extends Component {
  renderWeather(results) {
    const temp = results.list.map(weather => (weather.main.temp - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32);
    const pressure = results.list.map(weather => weather.main.pressure);
    const humidity = results.list.map(weather => weather.main.humidity);
    

    return (
      <tr key={results.city.id}>
        <td>{results.city.name}</td>
        <td>
          <Chart color='yellow' data={temp} units='F'/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Chart color='green' data={pressure} units='hPa'/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <Chart color='blue' data={humidity} units='%'/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Temperature</th>
            <th>Pressure</th>
            <th>Humidity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          { this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather) }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ weather }) {
  return { weather }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

Comment: This looks like a class component to me. Where is the function version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it depends *where* you want to get the `weather` data from.

1. You could pass it as a prop

```js
const WeatherList = (props) => {

    return (
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Temperature</th>
            <th>Pressure</th>
            <th>Humidity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.weather.map(weatherItem => {
              // contents of renderWeather
              //
            }
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )

}
```

2. You could grab it from the Redux Store via `useSelector`

```js
const WeatherList = (props) => {
    const weather = useSelector(store => store.pathInStore.weather);
    //
    // Continue as above
    //
}
```

Note: You don't have to do the `renderWeather` inside the map as an anonymous function, it may be simpler to refactor it out to its own `WeatherItem` component or something.

Answer (score 0):

`this.props` only works in class components it does not work in functional components. you have hooks to manage state inside a FC.

here is [Blog link](https://medium.com/hackernoon/react-hooks-migrate-class-component-to-functional-and-use-hooks-36a59b130cdc) to migrate from class base to function base in react.

Answer (score 0):

When refactoring Class components into Functional components you will lose "this", all your props will be no longer in `this.props`, you accept props as an argument in your functional component.

Use `useSelector` hook to get values from redux store.

Your final component will be something like this:

```
export const WeatherList(props){
  const weather = useSelector(weatherSelector);

  const renderWeather = (...) => {...} //Its better to move it to separate component

  return (
     ...
     {renderWeather(weather)}
     ...

  )
}
```